# How to split a string in tcl

Tags: split, arguments, tcl, divide

How do I split a string in tcl

consider the code :

```
set ip "12345678910"
```

I want to split the string into 4 strings as one set i.e 1234 5678 910 ....

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
regexp -all -inline {\d{1,4}} 12345678910
```

This will return a list with each element having 4 digits, except the last which can have fewer...

Answer (score 1):

I usually advise against using `regexp`, but `regexp -all -inline {\d{1,4}} 12345678910` as in Captain's answer might actually be the best solution. If the characters don't have to be digits, `regexp -all -inline {.{1,4}} 1a2b3c4d5e6` will allow any character in the string.

Another solution is to use `lmap {a b c d} [split 12345678910 {}] {lindex $a$b$c$d}`.

(The single-argument `lindex` invocation is just the identity function, i.e. the result is equal to the argument.)

Documentation: [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
set ip "12345678910"
set len [ string length $ip ]
set str_start 0; #Start Index
set str_end 3; #End Index

for { set i 0 }  { $str_start < $len } { incr i } { 
    #Appending it as 'list'
    lappend list_result [ string range $ip $str_start $str_end ]
    #Increasing the index values
    incr str_start 4
    incr str_end 4
}
puts $list_result
```

**Output**

```
1234 5678 910
```